# send-mailmessage opens file instead of sending it

Tags: powershell-2.0

Can anyone tell me why this opens instead of sends the file?

```
$d = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90)
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'lastLogon -le $d' -Properties lastLogon | 
Export-Csv c:\temp\stale_servers.csv    
If (c:\temp\stale_servers.csv = $?) 
{
 Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer xxxxxxxxx -To xxxxxxxxx -From xxxxxx -Subject "test mail" -Body "The servers that have not logged in, in the past 90 days are attached." -attachment c:\temp\stale_servers.csv
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is in this line:

```
If (c:\temp\stale_servers.csv = $?)
```

if you want to test the existence of the file use:

```
If (test-path -path "c:\temp\stale_servers.csv" )
```

Comment: Why is the output in the csv not accurate? It sometimes brings 85 servers and some times 3 servers, if I manually check the servers only the 3 are correct.

Comment: @TagYourIT hum.. try use `lastlogontimestamp`. Result does change?

Comment: result changed some, querying system owners

Comment: I found it. I want just servers.

Comment: Can you see a flaw in my logic; $d = [DateTime]::Today.AddDays(-90); Get-ADComputer -Filter {('lastlogontimestamp -le $d') -and ('operatingSystem -like *Server*')} -Properties lastLogon | Export-Csv c:\temp\stale_servers.csv